# youtube-dl problems (scripting)

Tags: bash, sed, youtube, youtube-dl

Okay, so I've got this small problem with a bash script that I'm writing.

This script is supposed to be run like this:

```
bash script.sh https://www.youtube.com/user/<channel name>
```

OR

```
bash script.sh https://www.youtube.com/user/<random characters that make up a youtube channel ID>
```

It downloads an entire YouTube channel to a folder named

```
<uploader>{<uploader_id>}/
```

Or, at least it SHOULD...

the problem I'm getting is that the archive.txt file that youtube-dl creates is not created in the same directory as the videos. It's created in the directory from which the script is run.

Is there a grep or sed command that I could use to get the archive.txt file to the video folder?

Or maybe create the folder FIRST, then cd into it, and run the command from there?
I dunno

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
sleep 1
echo "You entered: $1 for the URL"
sleep 1
echo "Now downloading all videos from URL "$1""
youtube-dl -iw \
--no-continue $1 \
-f bestvideo+bestaudio --merge-output-format mkv \
-o "%(uploader)s{%(uploader_id)s}/[%(upload_date)s] %(title)s" \
--add-metadata --download-archive archive.txt
exit 0
```

Comment: You are telling it to create the archive as `archive.txt` so that's going to happen in the current directory. Unless `youtube-dl` supports `%(uploader)s`, etc. in that argument also you are going to have trouble doing what you want here with just that one command (or any set of commands unless you have some other way of getting the uploader name and id somehow).

Comment: @EtanReisner , yeah, %(uploader)s, &tc is a variable that youtube-dl uses. This would be so much easier if youtube-dl just exported that as a bash variable, then I could just do a simple "cd"

Comment: It can't do that. That's just not possible. It *could* support the formats in the `--download-archive` argument though. Short of that you'll need to "parse" the output and move the file to the right directory manually after the download. This might be something that's worth filing a but with youtube-dl about.

Comment: @EtanReisner [done](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/9201). However, if they refuse to do that, do you know how I would go about parsing the output? I've tried with grep, but haven't really gotten very far.

Comment: You probably didn't want to copy the entire bug filing help text into the bug you filed. You probably also want to link to this question and explain *why* it would help you (let you put the archive file in the same directory as the channel contents, etc.)

Comment: I don't know what the output looks like offhand (or if it is regular enough to use) and I've never downloaded entire channels with youtube-dl.

Comment: @EtanReisner Here's some output: https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/4euubo/help_me_answer_this_question_about_youtubedl_and/

Comment: I don't see anything in there that is *too* obviously safe and usable. The, terse, commenter on the bug you filed indicated to "parse json" for this. What does the `--write-info-json` output file look like? What about the `--dump-json` or `--print-json` options?

Comment: Here's what running --print-json does: http://pastebin.com/exkmz9zP

Comment: Is the information you need for the directory name in that anywhere? (I didn't see anything obvious in a quick scan.)

Comment: No, I don't see it either. Regardless, I've at least got a functioning script working: https://github.com/TheSqrtMinus1/download-youtube-channel-hq/blob/master/script.sh

Comment: That seems like an answer to the question. Write it up and accept it (summarizing the bit of this comment thread about how the support isn't there for doing it automatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving it with this:

```
uploader="$(youtube-dl -i -J $URL --playlist-items 1 | grep -Po '(?<="uploader": ")[^"]*')"
uploader_id="$(youtube-dl -i -J $URL --playlist-items 1 | grep -Po '(?<="uploader_id": ")[^"]*')"
uploaderandid="$uploader{$uploader_id}"
echo "Uploader: $uploader"
echo "Uploader ID: $uploader_id"
echo "Folder Name: $uploaderandid"
echo "Now downloading all videos from URL "$URL" to the folder "$DIR/$uploaderandid""
```

Basically I had to parse the JSON with grep, since the youtube-dl devs said that implementing -o type variables into any other variable would clog up the code and make it bloated.